# How to extract a word in a string following one that matches something in a key word list

Tags: python, string, split

I am a newcomer to Python.  I can split a line of a file up into words, but haven't found out how to get at the word which follows a match to a set of key words.

```
    fread = open (F_FIXED_EERAM, 'r')
    KEYWORDS = ['tINT16', 'tUINT16', 'tGDT_TYPE']
    for line in fread.readlines():
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word in KEYWORDS:
    #       I want to append the word after the keyword to a new string in another file
    #       How do I get at that word?
    ...
```

Comment: it looks like you almost have it where are you failing?

Answer (score 3):

Just set a boolean to store the next word if a keyword was found:

```
KEYWORDS = ['tINT16', 'tUINT16', 'tGDT_TYPE']
result = []

with open (F_FIXED_EERAM, 'r') as fread:
    for line in fread:
        store_next = False
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if store_next:
                result.append(word)
                store_next = False
            elif word in KEYWORDS:
                store_next = True
```

`result` is now a list of all words that where preceded by one of the `KEYWORDS`.

I made the assumption if the last word of the previous line is a keyword, the first word on the next line doesn't have to be stored. If you do want this behaviour move `store_next = False` outside the (outer) `for` loop.

---

Or you could use a [`regular expression`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re

KEYWORDS = ['tINT16', 'tUINT16', 'tGDT_TYPE']

regex = '(?:{}) +(\\w+)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, KEYWORDS)))

with open ('in.txt', 'r') as file_:
    print(re.findall(regex, file_.read()))
```

This might look like magic, but this is the actual regular expression used:

```
(?:tINT16|tUINT16|tGDT_TYPE) +(\w+)
```

Which translates to: match one of the keywords followed by one or more spaces followed by a word. `?:` at the beginning tells Python not to store that group. `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (depending on LOCALE and UNICODE flags).

Comment: don't use `for line in file.readlines():`; do `for line in file:`.

Comment: use `'|'.join(map(re.escape, KEYWORDS))` to safeguard against a keyword containing non-safe regex symbol.

Comment: in general `\w` is not equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: There @J.F.Sebastian, anything else? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `enumerate(words)` giving you the following

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):
  if word in KEYWORDS:
    if(i+1<len(words)):
      str.append(word[i+1])
```

Or you can use the `re` library http://docs.python.org/library/re.html. Here you can specify a regular expression an easily parse out specific values straight into an array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code is what you want.
Please notice that if the keyword appears at the end of line, you need to add some special processing.

```
newstring = ''
fread = open (F_FIXED_EERAM, 'r')
KEYWORDS = ['tINT16', 'tUINT16', 'tGDT_TYPE']
for line in fread.readlines():
    words = line.split()
    for i in range(0,len(words)-1):
        if words[i] in KEYWORDS:
            newstring += words[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to keep track of the word you saw the *last* time through the loop. If this word is one of your keywords, then the *current* word is the word following it. It is natural to write this as a generator. It is also convenient to write a generator that returns the individual words (tokens) from a file.

```
def tokens_from(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            for token in line.split():
                yield token

def keyword_values(filename, *keywords):
    keywords = set(keywords)
    previous = None
    for token in tokens_from(filename):
        if previous in keywords:
            yield token
        previous = token
```

Now you can get the words into a list:

```
result = list(keyword_values(F_FIXED_EERAM, 'tINT16', 'tUINT16', 'tGDT_TYPE'))
```

Or you can build up a string:

```
result = " ".join(keyword_values(F_FIXED_EERAM, 'tINT16', 'tUINT16', 'tGDT_TYPE'))
```

Or you can iterate over them and write them to a file:

```
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
   for outword in keyword_values(F_FIXED_EERAM, 'tINT16', 'tUINT16', 'tGDT_TYPE'):
       print outword
```